# Python output to terminal during ssh login

Tags: python, ssh, terminal, ipod

I have been looking everywhere for this and have not found a solution. I am using python 2.5.1 on an Apple iPod and I am trying to connect to a host with SSH. First I start off with `import os`. Next I
`os.system('ssh 192.168.1.13)`. After this command is executed I next try to `os.system('password')`. This does not work and SSH asks for the password, after I exit the SSH session then my `password` is printed. Is there any way that I can get it so that it sends the password to SSH? I don't want to add any other modules to python. Thanks!

Complete file:

```
import os

os.system('ssh 192.168.1.13')
os.system('password')
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

take a look at [pexpect](http://pexpect.sourceforge.net/pexpect.html), it should do the trick in the manner you expect it.

Example from the docs:

```
child = pexpect.spawn('scp foo myname@host.example.com:.')
child.expect ('Password:')
child.sendline (mypassword)
```

Yes, that's yet another module.. but the cleanest way to accomplish what you want.

Comment: This is perfect! I guess I can make an exception and get a new module. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Or use passwordless, passphraseless ssh: http://stromberg.dnsalias.org/~strombrg/ssh-keys.html

No additional module required.