# How to accept password in command line argument for ssh login using python

Tags: python, linux, ssh

I am using ssh to login to a remote device. I have a python script for this. The command I run is:

> ./python_script.py ssh device@ip_address

I want to create a password with one of the arguments for this script. I have the following in my python script.

```
try:
    p = subprocess.Popen(
        ['ssh', '-s', '-l', '<name1>', <host_name>, '-p', str(port), '<something>'],
        bufsize=BUFSIZE,
        stdin=subprocess.PIPE,
        stdout=subprocess.PIPE,
        stderr=subprocess.STDOUT,
        shell=False)
except Exception, err:
    print 'Failed to run ssh command! (' + str(err) + ')'
    sys.exit()
```

I don't know if my question is clear but I would like to know how to get my ssh script to accept a password parameter. I want to access it from python script using `sys.argv[]`

Comment: I suggest you look at Python-LibSSH2: https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pylibssh2

Comment: This would definitely solve your issue: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10391859/python-output-to-terminal-during-ssh-login

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider the following usage:

```
./python_script.py ssh device@ip_address passwd
```

Now you access the arguments by:

```
import sys

if len(sys.argv) < 4:
    print("Not enough arguments!")
    sys.exit()

ssh        = sys.argv[1]
device     = sys.argv[2].split("@")[0]
ip_address = sys.argv[2].split("@")[1]
passwd     = sys.argv[3]
```

To call the `ssh` command along with your password, you'll need `sshpass`, [as described here](https://serverfault.com/a/512220).

Hope this helps!

Comment: Ok. So, may be my question is not clear. This answer is telling me how to access the commands given in command line. My question is to know if  there a way in which I can give password as one of the arguments along with ssh so that ssh doesn't prompt for password again. Else, what modifications can I do to my python code to use this password given in command line so that ssh doesn't ask for a password while logging into the remote device.

Comment: @KalyanamRajashree - I just gave you the hint about sshpass!

Comment: Awesome ! Worked like a miracle. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

There is library in python called fabric.Just read it you will get to how to do that.
Or install ssh-pass though github, it is also for the same purpose.

Answer (score 0):

So this is the final solution which worked for me.
I installed sshpass using

`sudo apt-get install sshpass`

Then my modified code is the following. I took `password` from command line as linusg suggested in above answer.

```
try:
    p = subprocess.Popen(
    ['sshpass','-p',password,'ssh', '-s', '-l', '<name1>', <host_name>, '-p', str(port), '<something>'],
    bufsize=BUFSIZE,
    stdin=subprocess.PIPE,
    stdout=subprocess.PIPE,
    stderr=subprocess.STDOUT,
    shell=False)
except Exception, err:
    print 'Failed to run ssh command! (' + str(err) + ')'
    sys.exit()
```